# If it is possible to login automatically after register laravel api using passport

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Register Api for Android App  stored And Return the response Success. I want know If its possible to Automatically Login if Register Success We are using

> php artisan make:auth

in Laravel Web

```
 public function signup(Request $request){

    try{
         $User = $request->all();
         if($request->has('referal_code')){
             $User['referal_code'] = $request->referal_code;
        }
         $User['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);
         $User['picture']  = 'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/';
         $User = User::create($User);
        return $User;
    }catch(Exception $e){
         return response()->json(['error' =>'api.something_went_wrong'], 500);
    }
 }
}
```

Login Api

```
  public function login(){ 
    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){ 
        $user = Auth::user(); 
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken; 
        return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this-> successStatus); 
    } 
    else{ 
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: you mean login in web if login in app?

Comment: @VasimVanzara Login in App

Comment: public function login(){ 
        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){ 
            $user = Auth::user(); 
            $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken; 
            return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this-> successStatus); 
        } 
        else{ 
            return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401); 
        } 
    }

Comment: yes @Ragupathi just return `$success['token'] = $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken;` after creating user and then at app side in signup success use this token and logged in user

Answer (score 1):

You created the user so it returns an user_id, with the user_id you can login the user.

```
Auth::loginUsingId($user_id);

// Login and "remember" the given user...
Auth::loginUsingId(1, true);
```

**Authenticate A User Instance**

```
Auth::login($user);

// Login and "remember" the given user...
Auth::login($user, true);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#other-authentication-methods

**For Passport**

You can add findForPassport into User model:

```
public function findForPassport($identifier) {
        return $this->orWhere('email', $identifier)->orWhere('username', $identifier)->first();
}
```

and add 'username' to $fillable

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'username'
];
```

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-passport-login-using-username-or-email?page=1

Comment: its possible in login api where Are Using Passport